# Justification for the existence of another arbitrarily close sequence

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, compactness

I am reading some notes related to compact operators. My question is what is the justification for the existence of the sequence $y_n$ that is within $1/n$ of $z_n$.

[image]

Comment: Hint: If $\{z_n\}_{n\in \mathbb N}$ is in $T(B)$ already then you can take $z_n=y_n \forall n$.  Otherwise at least one point of $\{z_n\}_{n\in \mathbb N}$ is an accumulation point of $T(B)$.

Comment: This has nothing to do with sequences. The definition of the closure implies that, for every $\varepsilon >0$, there is $y_n\in T(B)$ with $\|y_n-z_n\|<\varepsilon$. Apply this to $\varepsilon =1/n$.